# Stack trace error across multiple lines

Tags: log4net

I am using log4net to log errors in my C# application. I am logging the error to the csv file. I am also logging stack trace error to this log. But the issue is that the stack trace error is very long and is like 7 to 8 lines of error. So in the CSV file the output is coming out to be messy.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how can i log stack trace error better to either csv or excel so that the whole stacke trace error message comes in one cel rather than being split into different lines?

Comment: Am I getting this right: The problem is that the stacktrace column in your CSV gets separated over several lines. 

Could you post your current configuration?

Comment: yup..that is my problem.do you have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes for the stack trace and any other similar strings.